# How to do QtCreator's steps in compiling qt project manually?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm new in Qt and trying to do [a text editor example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html) from Qt 5. But, I'm doing that without QtCreator. Of course I have QtCreator installed, I just want to try doing that example without QtCreator. My steps in doing this are:

1. Write `main.cpp`, `notepad.cpp` and `notepad.h` exactly like in the
   example. (Except for `include` preprocessor, I write the complete
   path like:

   ```
   #include <qt/QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
   ```

   not just:

   ```
   #include <QMainWindow>
   ```
2. Create `notepad.ui` file with QtDesigner.
3. Generate `ui_notepad.h` file with `uic-qt5 notepad.ui > ui_notepad.h`
   command.
4. Generate `notepad.pro` file with `qmake-qt5 -project` command.
5. Add these lines in `notepad.pro` file:

   ```
   QT += core gui
   greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
   ```
6. Generate `Makefile` with `qmake` command.
7. Do `make` command.

Those step is what I can understand on how QtCreator doing the task automatically. And then, `make` complaints about incomplete type and forward declaration. But, If I'm doing this with QtCreator, the project is compiled just fine.

What did I miss there?

These are the error messages that I get:

```
notepad.cpp: In constructor ‘Notepad::Notepad(QWidget*)’:
notepad.cpp:4:72: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Ui::Notepad’
 Notepad::Notepad (QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow (parent), ui (new Ui::Notepad) {
                                                                    ^
In file included from notepad.cpp:1:0:
notepad.h:4:8: error: forward declaration of ‘class Ui::Notepad’
  class Notepad;
    ^
notepad.cpp:5:4: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Ui::Notepad’
  ui->setupUi (this);
    ^
In file included from notepad.cpp:1:0:
notepad.h:4:8: error: forward declaration of ‘class Ui::Notepad’
  class Notepad;
    ^
notepad.cpp: In destructor ‘virtual Notepad::~Notepad()’:
notepad.cpp:9:9: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [-Wdelete-incomplete]
  delete ui;
     ^
notepad.cpp:9:9: warning: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Ui::Notepad’
In file included from notepad.cpp:1:0:
notepad.h:4:8: warning: forward declaration of ‘class Ui::Notepad’
  class Notepad;
    ^
notepad.cpp:9:9: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
  delete ui;
     ^
Makefile:660: recipe for target 'notepad.o' failed
make: *** [notepad.o] Error 1
```

**Update**

ui_notepad.h file:

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'notepad.ui'
**
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.4.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_NOTEPAD_H
#define UI_NOTEPAD_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QWidget *centralwidget;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_2;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
    QPushButton *quitButton;
    QMenuBar *menubar;
    QStatusBar *statusbar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
    if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
        MainWindow->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainWindow"));
    MainWindow->resize(800, 600);
    centralwidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
    centralwidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralwidget"));
    verticalLayout_2 = new QVBoxLayout(centralwidget);
    verticalLayout_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout_2"));
    verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    verticalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout"));
    textEdit = new QTextEdit(centralwidget);
    textEdit->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("textEdit"));

    verticalLayout->addWidget(textEdit);

    quitButton = new QPushButton(centralwidget);
    quitButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("quitButton"));

    verticalLayout->addWidget(quitButton);


    verticalLayout_2->addLayout(verticalLayout);

    MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralwidget);
    textEdit->raise();
    quitButton->raise();
    menubar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
    menubar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menubar"));
    menubar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 27));
    MainWindow->setMenuBar(menubar);
    statusbar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
    statusbar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("statusbar"));
    MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusbar);

    retranslateUi(MainWindow);

    QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
    MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", 0));
    quitButton->setText(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "Quit", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_NOTEPAD_H
```

notepad.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit"/>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="quitButton">
    <property name="text">
     <string>Quit</string>
    </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
   <zorder>textEdit</zorder>
   <zorder>quitButton</zorder>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>27</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes namespaced in `Ui::` are automatically generated by the Qt UIC metacompiler after compiling `.ui` files. Your code expects `Ui::Notepad` to be generated and automatically linked into the project with qmake/uic.

After looking at the XML of the `.ui` file that QtDesigner creates, you can see the following line:

`<class>MainWindow</class>`

That means that the class `Ui::MainWindow` is generated. If you wanted to generate `Ui::Notepad` instead, open the `.ui` form in QtDesigner and rename the top level widget from `MainWindow` to `Notepad`. Then `Ui::Notepad` would appear in your project.

It would cause the XML to look like `<class>Notepad</class>` which would make `Ui::Notepad` available in your code

Comment: Yes, i've added `FORMS += notepad.ui` in `.pro` file. I think step number 3 I mentioned above was generating `Ui::Notepad` if I'm correct.

Comment: Can you locate a file ui_Notepad.cpp in your build directory

Comment: Nope. Just `ui_notepad.h` file. Is that `.cpp` file should be there?

Comment: Look inside ui_notepad.h and make sure there is a `Ui::Notepad` typedef

Comment: I can't find any typedef there

Comment: Then you have a naming problem. Can you post your `ui_notepad.h` file and your `.ui` file  in their entirety?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75023/discussion-between-joseph-malicke-and-bagol-daplun).